# XNA 4.0 Disappearing Objects - Effects, light (?)

Tags: c#, xna, light, procedural

XNA 4.0 - Project link availible below.

Problem: When I move away my camera, planets seem to slowly vanish. Looks as if the light fades away or something.

I tried changing far plane and near plane to different values and it doesnt change anything.

Scenario:

1. The program creates spheres (not using models) using user indexed primivites.
2. Then textures are created using custom rules and algorithm. I know for sure that those textures are generated fine.
3. This is where it gets tricky because Im a noob at effects. (I didnt create the effects file so I have little understanding (despite alot of trying) of how to adjust it.)  So thats to the custom .fx file - the textures are applied to spheres and lightning is applied. I think the problem may lie somewhere here.
4. After that not much happens that could have any impact on appearance. Only other thing that comes to mind are view and projection matrices.

I post the effects file here as well as the whole project (300 kb) It should run on any machine I guess if you want to try it out. Edit: forgot to mention-in menu press space to select "play"

Dropbox link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/819242/Procedural%20Planet%20Problem.zip

Effects file: http://pastebin.com/jcirdfXJ

I put the effects file on pastebin because when I copied it to this post, the formatting looked terrible (even when using the "code" option).

I hope somebody can enlighten me because Im really desperate at the moment.

Comment: Is the fade effect similar to this? http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IhD8foaTv0A/T-yvUgfS16I/AAAAAAAAAmM/9Ygn12v0Ups/s1600/BumpTerrainWithSMFog.JPG

Its called fog if so

Comment: I wouldnt say its fog related. I was reading about fog yesterday and investigating if its the problem. 

http://i.imgur.com/Jy4ycHx.jpg       Notice how the sphere becomes darker at edges and slowly (with camera moving away) the centre disappears the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have enabled mip mapping in the diffuse texture creation...

Disable it and it will be displayed right.

Comment: After even more reading I found where i need to disable mipmaping... jeez im so blind. Thanks very much!! TIL